# SageMaker delete Models and Endpoint configurations with python API

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I've tried deleting/recreating endpoints with the same name, and wasted a lot of time before I realized that changes do not get applied unless you also delete the corresponding Model and Endpoint configuration so that new ones can be created with that name.

Is there a way with the sagemaker python api to delete all three instead of just the endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like AWS is currently in the process of supporting model deletion via API with [this](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/pull/647) pull request.

For the time being Amazon's only [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-cleanup.html) is to delete everything via the console.

If this is critical to your system you can probably manage everything via Cloud Formation and create/delete services containing your Sagemaker models and endpoints.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are looking for something like this? :

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_endpoint_config

Examples:

```
import boto3

deployment_name = 'my_deployment_name'
client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
response = client.describe_endpoint_config(EndpointConfigName=deployment_name)
model_name = response['ProductionVariants'][0]['ModelName']
client.delete_model(ModelName=model_name)    
client.delete_endpoint(EndpointName=deployment_name)
client.delete_endpoint_config(EndpointConfigName=deployment_name)
```

Comment: Yup that works thanks. Was able to pull the latest sagemaker build to use the PR suggested, but this is nice when I can't do that.